# Splunk Conditional Dedup and Other FIlters

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Is it possible to conditionally apply a filter, for example `dedup` based on an `if` statement or a `where`

For example:

```
(initial search)
| dedup field(s) | where var1=true
| table field(s)
```

Or:

````
(initial search)
| if(var1=true, dedup field(s))
| table field(s)```
````

Answer (score 1):

The `dedup` command does not have a conditional option nor can a Splunk command be executed conditionally.

When the checkbox is clicked, set a token to "dedup field(s)"; otherwise, set it to "noop". Reference the token in your search. (initial search) | $token$ | table field(s)

Comment: I'd like to `dedup` if a dashboard token is set to true. Basically, if the checkbox is selected, show all of the results. If it is unselected, show just the non-duplicated results.

Comment: When the checkbox is clicked, set a token to "dedup field(s)"; otherwise, set it to "noop".  Reference the token in your search.  `(initial search) | $token$ | table field(s)`.

Comment: Can you post this in a reply, so I can mark as correct? @RichG